# Imagem capturada do SQLite fica com fundo preto no ImageView

Tags: android, bitmap

Em minha aplicação, tenho a necessidade de capturar uma imagem que está em uma base `SQLite` no formato `byte` (Blob) e depois converte-la para `Bitmap` a fim de a exibir em uma `ImageView`.

O meu problema é que o espaço do `ImageView` que sobra na horizontal fica sempre com fundo preto.

**`layout.xml`**

```
<LinearLayout 
    android:orientation="horizontal" 
    android:layout_width="match_parent" 
    android:layout_height="match_parent" 
    android:layout_weight="1"> 

    <ImageView 
        android:layout_width="match_parent" 
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
        android:id="@+id/imageView1" 
        android:layout_weight="1" 
        android:src="@drawable/foto_default" /> 

</LinearLayout>
```

Método de conversão:

```
private void setImage(){
    byte[] outImage = lista.get(position).getFoto(); 
    ByteArrayInputStream imageStream = new ByteArrayInputStream(outImage); 
    Bitmap imagemConvertida = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(imageStream); 
    foto.setImageBitmap(imagemConvertida);
}
```

Podem-me ajudar?

Comment: Olá. Poderia, por favor, editar sua pergunta com uma imagem de como sua `ImageView` está, o código de como você está fazendo esta conversão e também o layout (.xml) em que sua `ImageView` está?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Consegui resolver o meu problema. O problema estava no código que converte a imagem de Bitmap para bytes. Eu estava a gravar a imagem como JPEG e não podia. A imagem tinha de ser gravada como PNG. Aqui vai o código corrigido:

`imageView.buildDrawingCache();
Bitmap imagemDoImageview = imageView.getDrawingCache();
ByteArrayOutputStream stream = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
imagemDoImageview.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.PNG, 100, stream);
byte[] imageInByte = stream.toByteArray();`